# Pause iteration

Tags: lua

I have Lua table, `t`, which I iterate:

```
for k, v in pairs(t) do
    b = false
    my_func(v)
end
```

and want iteration to pause until `b` global variable changes to `true`

Is it possible is Lua?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It seems like you are approaching your actual problem in the wrong way.

Comment: I'm calling UI dialog with my_func function which returns value when user presses button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you're in a coroutine, there's no concept of a Lua variable changing value *without* your code doing it. So you would be pausing until something that can't possibly happen happens. Lua is inherently single-threaded.

As previously stated, you can use a coroutine to do this, but you'll have to modify your code accordingly:

```
function CoIterateTable(t)
  for k, v in pairs(t) do
    b = false
    my_func(v)

    while(b == false) do coroutine.yield() end
  end
end

local co = coroutine.create(CoIterateTable)

assert(co.resume(t))
--Coroutine has exited. Possibly through a yield, possibly returned.
while(co.running()) do
  --your processing between iterations.
  assert(co.resume(t))
end
```

Note that changing the table referenced by `t` between iterations is not going to do something useful.